# Draw "static position" on ViewPager canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I extended the ViewPager with my class and overriden onDraw void like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    ...
}
```

the problem is that whatever I draw in there, it scrolls with the ViewPager, but I want it to stay on the same place. I already tried setting `canvas.translate(0,0);` but that didn't work.

I would really appreciate any solution how to make the draw position static.

Comment: What is the use of ViewPager in your case..??

Comment: `translate(0, 0)` will do nothing, you need to reset the `Canvas` transformation `Matrix`, try calling `Canvas#getMatrix` and see its Matrix#MTRANS_X value, then you need to call `translate(-transX, 0)` or use `Canvas#setMatrix` to completely replace the `Matrix` but it is tricky

Comment: @SarithaG Swiping between fragments.

Comment: You have to take separate view to draw that custom view, and viewpager is an another view which  you should create in your xml file.

Comment: another option is to override `dispatchDraw` here the `Canvas` should not be translated

Comment: @pskink I tried to override it, but it is still translated.

Comment: so use `translate()` i wrote in my first comment

Comment: @pskink Thank you, it works.

Comment: @pskink But for some reason `Canvas.getMatrix()` is deprecated so I am not sure if I should use it as a solution.

Comment: ok, forget it, just use: `canvas.translate(getScrollX(), 0);`

Comment: Thanks :) please post it as answer so I can accept it and others can notice that this question is answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easy solution is to `translate()` your `Canvas` before drawing your stuff:

```
canvas.translate(getScrollX(), 0);
// your drawing code follows...
```